# Symfony2 Error: No mapping file found named

Tags: doctrine, symfony, mapping, entity

I am using Symfony2 and when i try to generate the schema ($ php app/console doctrine:generate:schema) i got an error..

```
    [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                             
      No mapping file found named 'xxx.UserBundle.Entity.User.php' for class 'xxx\UserBundle\Entity\User'.
```

I only have 2 Bundles in the proyect:

- UserBundle
- FileBundle

I connect the FileBundle with the UserBundle with this code:

```php
     
    /** 
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="xxx\UserBundle\Entity\User") 
    **/
    protected $user;
```

The headers of the files are something like this:

```php
    
    namespace xx\UserBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Entity
     **/
    class User
    { ###...###}
```

FileBundle is very similar..
Thanks!

Comment: I assume `xxx` and `xx` are just substitutions, are they?

Comment: I added the answer... but it's a long shot :)

Answer (score 27):

You are mixing Doctrine mapping formats, you have annotations and at least one XML file in Resources/config/doctrine

From the symfony docs:

```
"A bundle can accept only one metadata definition format. For example,
it's not possible to mix YAML metadata definitions with annotated PHP
entity class definitions."
```

So the solution is:

You cannot mix different Doctrine mapping formats in a given bundle. So either use annotations for all entities or use XML for all.

Comment: This solved my issue and it's still a valid restriction in Symfony 2.1, see symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information. Thanks

Comment: thank you, honestly. this saved me tons of debugging hours. I will never use auto generation of objects again

Answer (score 5):

It is somehow strange to me that you're using PHPDriver for ORM and not AnnotationDriver, since your database info in classes is in annotations.

Anyhow, if `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` command gives you only 1 entity that means that your other bundle containing User class is not loaded in app/AppKernel.php file. Load your UserBundle by adding line

```
new xxx\UserBundle\xxxUserBundle(),
```

to the `$bundles` array in `registerBundles()` function. After that, this function should look something like this:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        new xx\FileBundle\xxFileBundle(),
        new xxx\UserBundle\xxxUserBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

Of course, change 'xx' and 'xxx' with your real names.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @ilanco 100%. In addition, the solution is to REMOVE any .xml file in folder, for example:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\localxyz\src\AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Comment.orm.xml

these xml files created when you run such command:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\localxyz>php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle xml

Dung.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

Although I know that this has been posted years ago, but will just like to post my answer here, perhaps it could help someone :)

just simply clear the cache, it works for me though

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason why this is happening but I will take a leap here.

Try editing your `config.yml`. `doctrine` section should look like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: my_connection_name
        connections:
            fmefb:
                host:     %database_host%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                user:     %database_user%
                password: %database_password%
                driver:   %database_driver%
                port:     %database_port%
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: my_entity_manager
        entity_managers:
            my_entity_manager:
                connection: my_connection_name
                mappings:
                    CompanyNameSiteBundle: ~
                    CompanyNameAdminBundle: ~
                    CompanyNameSomethingElse: ~
```

Notice the `mappings` list on the bottom. All bundles which are "linked" are included here.

Hope this helps....

Comment: i use $php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
Found 1 entities mapped in entity manager default:
[OK]   xx\FileBundle\Entity\File, any idea?