# Use only annotations to define mapping rules for doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

I want to make doctrine use only the annotations existing inside the entity class (Not YAML).

When I execute: `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` , I get the error message:

```
Invalid mapping file 'TEST.Bundle.BlogBundle.Entity.Image.orm.yml' for clas
s 'TEST\Bundle\BlogBundle\Entity\Image'.
```

The file `TEST.Bundle.BlogBundle.Entity.Image.orm.yml` is empty. What can be the causes behind this error?

How can I tell doctrine to take into consideration the metadata specified by annotations?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of PHP do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the file:

```
TEST.Bundle.BlogBundle.Entity.Image.orm.yml
```

**Note: based on Symfony2 Docs**

```
"A bundle can accept only one metadata definition format. For example,
it's not possible to mix YAML metadata definitions with annotated PHP
entity class definitions."
```

Comment: After using your answer, the problem is resolved. however, I want to ask a question. Can I, under the same project, use YAML for some entities and annotations for others? If both are used for an enitity, is YAML always prior?

Comment: Actually, I got `No mapping file found named` error under my browser. I think I need to specify in configuration that I should use annotations for that specific entity and keep YAML for the others. right?

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces I don't know exactly, in your case saw that yaml is more priority.

Comment: About different formats, try to ask another question, maybe it possibly to do. But better stick to one format

Comment: can you please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525513/symfony2-error-no-mapping-file-found-named, ilanco answer.

Comment: Thanks. So different bundle can have different formats. Try to use different bundles for your entities for your aims

Comment: Ok nice Idea. In fact I am a newbie to symfony2, I should lear how to uses different bundles for one project. Thank you.

Comment: Use code generators. I use NetBeans which can simplicity execute symfony commands for create bundles, entities, etc.

Comment: yes, with Netbeans I see that it is more easier to execute symfony2 commands. No need now to open the black dos command line :-). Many thanks.