# No mapping file found named

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Error: No mapping file found named 'AppBundle.Entity.User.php' for class 'AppBundle\Entity\User'.

User.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="accounts")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=256)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
     */
    protected $alias;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $updated_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=5)
     */
    protected $currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=5)
     */
    protected $alternative_currency;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=2)
     */
    protected $level;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=10)
     */
    protected $exp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    protected $activation_code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    protected $recovery_key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $recovery_time;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=1)
     */
    protected $tutorial;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=1)
     */
    protected $last_zone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="int", length=1)
     */
    protected $chat_status;

    protected $remember_me;

    protected $em;

    public function getEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getAlias(){
        return $this->alias;
    }

    public function setAlias($alias){
        $this->alias = $alias;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(){
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt($created_at) {
        $this->created_at = $created_at;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(){
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt($updated_at) {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;
    }

    public function getCurrency(){
        return $this->currency;
    }

    public function setCurrency($currency){
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }

    public function getAlternativeCurrency(){
        return $this->alternative_currency;
    }

    public function setAlternativeCurrency($alternative_currency){
        $this->alternative_currency = $alternative_currency;
    }

    public function getLevel(){
    return $this->level;
}

    public function setLevel($level){
        $this->level = $level;
    }

    public function getExp(){
        return $this->exp;
    }

    public function setExp($exp){
        $this->exp = $exp;
    }

    public function getActivationCode(){
        return $this->activation_code;
    }

    public function setActivationCode($activation_code){
        $this->activation_code = $activation_code;
    }

    public function getRecoveryKey(){
        return $this->recovery_key;
    }

    public function setRecoveryKey($recovery_key){
        $this->recovery_key = $recovery_key;
    }

    public function getRecoveryTime(){
        return $this->recovery_time;
    }

    public function setRecoveryTime($recovery_time){
        $this->recovery_time = $recovery_time;
    }

    public function getTutorial(){
        return $this->tutorial;
    }

    public function setTutorial($tutorial){
        $this->tutorial = $tutorial;
    }

    public function getLastZone(){
        return $this->last_zone;
    }

    public function setLastZone($last_zone){
        $this->last_zone = $last_zone;
    }

    public function getChatStatus(){
        return $this->chat_status;
    }

    public function setChatStatus($chat_status){
        $this->chat_status = $chat_status;
    }

    public function getRememberMe(){
        return $this->remember_me;
    }

    public function setRememberMe($remember_me){
        $this->remember_me = $remember_me;
    }

}
```

config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true, enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I have read most of the answers i could find on google, tried all and still this error. If you need addional files, don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Does this question and solution apply to your problem ? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525513/symfony2-error-no-mapping-file-found-named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525513/symfony2-error-no-mapping-file-found-named)

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't, i don't see where i have mixed yml,xml and etc.

Comment: @PenchoSlaveikov if you have a folder doctrine in `Resources/config` then rename it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html):

> A namespace becomes a bundle as soon as you add a bundle class to it. The bundle class name must follow these simple rules:
>
> ...
> **Prefix the name with the concatenation of the vendor (and optionally the category namespaces);**

The Doctrine Bundle relies on this convention to find your metadata. So the namespace of your bundle should be something like `YourName\AppBundle`.

Comment: Not sure about that. The Symfony best practices suggest to NOT use a vendor name on the main app bundle, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles.