# Symfony2 Update Error.No mapping file

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am using Symfony2 and when i try to append FOSUserBundle, but i got an error
(bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force)

//---------------------------------------------------------------Appkernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new main\kipeoBundle\kipeoBundle(),
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),

    ];
```

//----------------------------------------------------app/config/config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: main\kipeoBundle\Entity\User
```

//----------------------------------------src-main>kipeoBundle>Entity>User.php

```
namespace main\kipeoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------app/config/routing.yml

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Comment: What is the path of your bundle ? Is it `src/main/kipeoBundle` ? Otherwise, your structure is wrong.

Comment: [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  No mapping file found named 'User.orm.xml' for class 'main\kipeoBundle\Entity\User'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Error: No mapping file found named](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525513/symfony2-error-no-mapping-file-found-named)

Comment: are you using `yml` format for you other entities ?

Comment: yes i using yml format

Answer (score 0):

In doctrine config, you need to specify the mapping type. In this case, "annotation"